# Dot font for tocloft

Tags: tocloft

I desire dots from the chapter to the page number in my table of contents. I also want the chapters not be bold type for title and page number. I can make the dots well enough, and have even been able to change their spacing.  But despite what I have fiddled with, the dots remain in bold font even when the surrounding text is plain.

Here's an MWE

```tex
\documentclass{report}
\title{Fake Title}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}  % table of contents control and formatting
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is the report's abstract.
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Fake Chapter}
\section{Fake Section}
\lipsum
\section{More Fakeness}
\lipsum
\subsection{Even More!}
\lipsum

\chapter{Fake Chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The table of contents for this MWE prints as shown. What can I do to control the appearance of the dots?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I just went digging through the `tocloft` documentation and came across this hidden gem:

```tex
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}
```

Getting rid of that `\bfseries` gives me what I needed.
[image: TOC without bolded leaders]